# Why Doesn't My AWS S3 Bucket Policy Override My IAM Policy?

Tags: permissions, amazon-web-services, policy, bucket, amazon-iam

I have a user in my IAM account called "testuser" who has administrator privileges, like so:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then I have a policy on my S3 bucket that denies this user access, like so:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "my-account-id:user/testuser"
  },
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the explicit deny in the S3 bucket policy should override the allow from the IAM policy right?  But when I log in as testuser, I still have access to everything in that bucket - I even have access to change or remove the bucket policy for that bucket (and every other bucket too).  Why isn't my explicit deny doing anything?

Comment: By access to everything to you mean just listing the bucket contents or can you also get/put files?

Comment: I mean everything - viewing files, adding files, viewing the bucket policy, editing the bucket policy, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the full ARN form for the user ID in the bucket policy:

```
"Principal": {
  "AWS":["arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/testuser"]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response - unfortunately this didn't have any effect

Comment: The policies you have specified should prevent `testuser` from getting/putting/deleting objects within the bucket but will _not_ prevent them from listing the bucket contents.  For that you'd have to use `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*","arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"]` in the deny rule (because actions like `ListBucket` are controlled by the bucket ARN rather than the bucket/* one).

Comment: @Ian, Your explanation in above comment stands good even after more than 1.5 years. It just helped me.

Comment: How does one write a bucket policy to override the IAM policy for all users in that account?